# Ocelot not being tamed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tamed an ocelot with raw cod, and I was letting it walk towards me, and it also showed hearts when I fed it. But it didn't change to a tamed ocelot, and it won't sit.
I'm on laptop 1.4.

Comment: What does "i'm on laptop 1.4" mean? Also, the ocelot is probably not actually tamed. I'm not sure why it shows heart particles, but you often need to feed it multiple times.

Comment: PC 1.4 @FabianRöling

Comment: @Robbie Well, that clears things up.

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. There is no version numbering for all PCs in the world.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. He's on a Windows PC running Minecraft 1.4

Comment: PC has two versions: Java Edition, 1.4 of which was released in 2012 (current version: 1.14.3), and Bedrock Edition (PC version of which is called Windows 10 Edition) 1.4 of which was released in May, 2018 (and the current version is 1.11.4). Getting the version is rather important because recently the mechanics changed significantly, and if you have 1.14.x or Bedrock counterpart for that, ocelots are not tameable anymore.

Answer (score 1):

On the Minecraft wiki it says

"If the player fails to tame an ocelot, it will still show smoke particles. They will still go into breeding mode..."

So you've just gotta keep trying. There is a 1/3 chance it will fail.